# Need a specific email to FOSS?

Tags: cloudbees

I already have a free user account into cloudbees.

Now I need to setup the account of my approved FOSS project. I couldn't use my personal email for this. This means that I need to create an specific email for the open source project?

Answer (score 3):

We (cloudbees) also can convert your FREE account to FOSS if you wish. please then reply to your approval email asking for the conversion

Answer (score 1):

Many email providers (such as Google) will deliver email to an account if the address includes the account name followed by some delimiter and some arbitrary characters.

So if your email address is foo@gmail.com, you will receive mail from foo+1@gmail.com, foo+abc@gmail.com, etc. In this way, you can create multiple unique accounts on CloudBees which all map to a single email inbox.

http://lifehacker.com/144397/instant-disposable-gmail-addresses

This probably works on all the other webmail providers, but that's a guess.

Comment: Also - once the account is created you can change the permissions so that you have one user account (email) to manage all your organisational accounts. So this disposable address need only be temporary.